# RWD Minicart - Error occurred. Try to refresh page

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd

I've just started out with the `RWD theme` of Magento for our store and whenever try to use the `minicart` function to update the cart with Ajax I get the following error

> Error occurred. Try to refresh page.

Refreshing the page does indeed update the cart, but it's not the best customer experience.

I've not made any code changes to the `minicart` and was wondering if anyone had encountered the same issue.

Comment: Check this out: http://j2store.org/support/documentation/186-how-to-solve-mini-cart-module-related-issues.html

Comment: After running the developer console I did find that an invalid form key is being passed, which generates the error. I'm trying to add form keys now to see if that resolves it.